# jQuery: Radio .change function, strange bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a selected radio after the .change event is triggered. I need to use an external function to do so but I cannot seem to get the correct value.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1.0"> 1.0
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2.0"> 2.0
```

jQuery:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='myradio']").change(function() {

    //SHOWING GOOD VALUE
    radio_value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    alert(radio_value);

    TEST();

}

function TEST(){

    //SHOWING WRONG VALUE
    radio_value = parseFloat($("input[type='radio'][name='myradio']:checked").val());
    alert(radio_value); 

}
```

For example, if I click the radio 1.0 is checked and I click the radio 2.0, the above jquery code will output 2.0 for the first alert and 1.0 for the second. The TEST() function output the old value, it seems like if the radio event has not happened yet.

I need to find a way to get the good radio value in the TEST() function without transferring any parameter to it.

How can I do such thing?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4MTxf/

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome -> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8qXd/3/) ??

Comment: @j08691 - did'nt see you there, beat me by 7 seconds.

Comment: @adeneo - great minds think alike, and type alike apparently.

Comment: Just a guess, you don't happen to have two radios with name="myradio"?

Comment: @JoshNoe - why? that's perfectly legal.

Comment: @j08691 my mistake, I didn't see he was selecting using :checked.  I figured his selector was getting both radios and val() was returning the value of the first.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, actually the problem was coming from a special plugin I had installed to style my radio buttons.

Comment: `.change(...` is unbalanced.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `TEST()` function:

```
var radio_value = parseFloat($("input[type='radio'][name='myradio']").val());
```

Since they have the same name, you shouldn't need to worry about using `:checked`, and although I'm not sure *why*, it seems that may be the cause of what you're seeing.

ps: Do you *really* mean to be setting a global `radio_value` variable in these functions?  I assumed "no" and prefixed the `var` declaration.

Comment: I just tried this in IE and I am always getting the first value (1.0).